# Angular 8 get AWS Cognito User Session

Tags: amazon-cognito, angular8

I'm trying to read AWS Cognito User Session in Angular 8 project.

Step 1: Added "amazon-cognito-identity-js": "3.2.1" to my package.json

Step 2: In my component file, imported the package as,

```
import { CognitoUser, CognitoUserSession } from 'amazon-cognito-identity-js';
```

Step 3: Injected into my constructor as,

```
constructor(private hc: HttpClient, private cu: CognitoUser, private cus: CognitoUserSession) { }
```

Step 4: Reading the user session in my function as,

```
this.cus = this.cu.getSignInUserSession();
```

Step 5: From command prompt, executed "ng build --prod" and I get below errors,

-------------------ERROR------------------

ERROR in ./src/app/features/MYcomponent.ngfactory.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'amazon-cognito-identity-js/index' in 'C:...'
resolve 'amazon-cognito-identity-js/index' in 'C:...'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: C:...\package.json (relative path: ./src/app/features/...)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    resolve as module
      looking for modules in C:/.../
        using description file: C:...\package.json (relative path: .)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          using description file: C:...\package.json (relative path: ./amazon-cognito-identity-js/index)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:...\amazon-cognito-identity-js\index doesn't exist            .ts
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration

---